# Is that possible to bind a new property for an existing class's instance like JavaScript in c++?

Tags: c++

We know in JavaScript you can assign a new property for an object like this:

```
var v = {};
.....
v.p = 1;
```

How about in C++? Is there any anything we can do like this:

```
MyClass* v = new MyClass();
...................
v->p = 1;   // p is not a member of MyClass.
```

I know in general this is not supported in C++, and this is not the way we can do it.

Is there the any magic thing we can bind a new property for an existing object in C++?

The reason why I want this is because I am using a third-party library, and I need simply extend it a little bit.

Comment: You really don't want to do anything like this.  C++ is not javascript, there are always other solutions.  Use composition instead

Comment: `myObject.addFunction<ReturnType,ArgumentType>(myFunction, "functionName"); myObject.applyfunction("functionName")(arguments)` the obvious solution (but problem with variadic template): no checking at compile time, just like in dynamically typed languages. Why you can't extend object from library not in runtime?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. They key reason is that C++ is statically typed (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type-checking) so for type safety reasons, an object's type is fixed at compile time. What you're doing by added a new property like that is dynamically changing the type, which is a key feature of languages like javascript and python.

You COULD come up with some bespoke solution, but I fear it would end up pretty unpleasant, and would have restrictions not present in a dynamically typed language.

Comment: Add `map` to the answer! :) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Answer (score 1):

If you set up your class appropriately, you can add properties to it. For example, I'm sometimes deriving from a base class which allows *attachments*:

```
class attachments {
public:
    template <typename T> T& attach();
};
class MyClass: public attachments { ... };

struct Something { int x; };

int main() {
    MyClass object;
    object.attach<Something>().x = 10;
    std::cout << attach<Something>().x;
}
```

The magic here is, of course, in the class `attachments` which basically maintains a sequence of `std::unique_ptr<attachment_base>` which get initialized with a suitable derived object upon first access. Note quite the automatic approach JavaScript supports but a reasonably dynamic way for a statically typed language.

The implementation of `attachments` is something along those lines:

```
class attachments {
    struct base { virtual ~base() {} };
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<base> > values_;
    static int next_id() { static int rc(0); return rc++; }
    template <typename>
    static int get_id() {  static int rc = next_id(); return rc; }
    template <typename T>
    struct attachment: base { T value; }; 
public:
    template <typename T>
    T& attach() {
        std::unique_ptr<base>& value = this->values_[get_id<T>()];
        if (!value) {
            value = std::unique_ptr<base>(new attachment<T>());
        }
        return *static_cast<T*>(value.get());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with vanilla C++, but it is certainly doable with a custom implementation. Qt's property system allows adding dynamic properties during the runtime which do not exist during compile time.

> QObject::setProperty() can also be used to add new properties to an
>   instance of a class at runtime. When it is called with a name and a
>   value, if a property with the given name exists in the QObject, and if
>   the given value is compatible with the property's type, the value is
>   stored in the property, and true is returned. If the value is not
>   compatible with the property's type, the property is not changed, and
>   false is returned. But if the property with the given name doesn't
>   exist in the QObject (i.e., if it wasn't declared with Q_PROPERTY(), a
>   new property with the given name and value is automatically added to
>   the QObject, but false is still returned. This means that a return of
>   false can't be used to determine whether a particular property was
>   actually set, unless you know in advance that the property already
>   exists in the QObject.